# By direct calculation for $f(z)=\cos(z),\sin(z), \text{ and } e^z$, verify that $f(0)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}f(\alpha^n)/k$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\alpha \neq 1$ be any $k^{th}$ root of unity for $k>2$. By direct calculation for $f(z)=\cos(z),\sin(z), \text{ and } e^z$, verify that $f(0)=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}f(\alpha^n)}{k}$. This formula suggests that the value of the function $f(z)$ at the center of the unit circle is the same as the average of its values at the $k^{th}$ roots of unity.

So for this problem I chose $k=3$ and $\alpha=2\pi$. So $\cos(0)=1$, $\sin(0)=0$, and $e^0=1$.

$$\frac{\sum_{n=0}^2\cos((2\pi)^n)}{3}=\frac{\cos((2\pi)^0)+\cos((2\pi)^1)+\cos((2\pi)^2)}{3}$$ But this is equal to $\frac{1}{3}$ not $1$. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is $2\pi$ a 3rd root of unity?

Comment: Oh I see that is where my problem lies

Comment: What would be a good choice of $\alpha$?